# PHP how to remove item from session when not in use

Tags: php, session

On my website, I allow users to view a users information by simply clicking their name. Once they click the persons name, they can schedule the person to come to an event. When the user clicks "schedule me" I take the them full name from the "user_id" and send it as a "$_SESSION['speaker']" to the next file that pretty much checks if the user came from the last file and takes the name and uses it as the input value for the calendar. The problem I am having is that when the user didn't "click schedule" from the other file and goes to the calendar website alone, the name from the previous person they clicked stays there and I want it to be blank in case they want to put a different name. So pretty much i would access the calendar website just by typing the URL and the name would still be in the session. I want to clear the session without logging the user out so they don't see the name of the previous person they clicked. Here is some of my code

First file

```
$_GET['speaker'] = $_SESSION['speaker_id'];
    $speaker_id = $_GET['speaker'];
    $stmtSpeaker = $handler->prepare("SELECT * FROM formdata WHERE user_id= :speaker_id");
    $stmtSpeaker->bindParam(':speaker_id', $speaker_id, PDO::PARAM_INT);
    $stmtSpeaker->execute();
    $formData = $stmtSpeaker->fetch();
    if(isset($_POST['schedule_me'])){

        $_SESSION['admin'] = $adminBoolean;
        $_SESSION['speaker'] = $formData['fullname'];
        $_SESSION['speaker_came'] = true;
        header("Location: admincalendar.php");
        exit;
    }
```

Second file

```
$adminBoolean = $resultChecker['admin'];
if($_SESSION['speaker_came'] = true){

    $speaker = $_SESSION['speaker'];

}else{

    $speaker = "";
}
```

Comment: `unset` your $_SESSION['speaker'] value. But why using sessions? Can't you write your code in a more clear way? With function calls, for instance. Using sessions to pass temporary values to business logic code is not really nice

Comment: I thought that was the logical way of going around my issue

Answer (score 0):

Unset will destroy a particular session variable whereas session_destroy() will destroy all the session data for that user.

It really depends on your application as to which one you should use. Just keep the above in mind.

```
unset($_SESSION['name']); // will delete just the name data

session_destroy(); // will delete ALL data associated with that user.
```

Answer (score 0):

You can unset session variable

```
$adminBoolean = $resultChecker['admin'];
if($_SESSION['speaker_came'] = true){
 $speaker = $_SESSION['speaker'];
}else{
    unset($_SESSION['speaker']);
    unset($_SESSION['speaker_came']);
    $speaker = '';
}
```

Comment: When i use that way, I still get it. Do you think I shouldn't use the session to store the data? Cause I think it stays until i either logout or click another name

Comment: You can add one parameter in redirect url in your first file like  
header("Location: admincalendar.php?isReirect = true");
and check in second file if you get this value then use $_SESSION['speaker']  otherwise empty $speaker = '';

Comment: hmm D: I did that and still got the same value.

Comment: in second file check if condition their must be "==" instead of single "="
if($_GET['isReirect'] == true){    
    $speaker = $_SESSION['speaker'];   
}else{
    $speaker = "";
}

Answer (score 0):

You need to first get the tempkey of the element and then unset it. Try this:

```
if(($tempkey = array_search($speaker_id, $_SESSION['speaker'])) !== FALSE)
   unset($_SESSION['speaker'][$tempkey]);
```

Comment: I put that in my second file right? if so I got a lot of errors "( ! ) Fatal error: Cannot unset string offsets in C:\wamp64\www\website\admincalendar.php on line 34
"

Comment: Please check $speaker_id, $_SESSION['speaker'] and $tempkey values in same file.

Comment: i did put it in the same file